# Determine if an algorithm has solutions or not

Tags: cryptography

I m actually studying Turing works concerning Enigma's machine.

Actually, I am wondering if it does exist anything, an algorithm or something that allows people to tlel if an algorithm can be break or not.

For example, admitting that we're working on the AES cryptographic cypher, how can we know that we can reverse the code ?

How are they different from hash algorithm ?

Comment: Conceptually, if it wasn't reversible, it would be a pretty terrible code, because it couldn't be used to transmit information in the first place.

Comment: Yes but does it exist a way to, mathematically, determine if the algorithm can be solved without using the reverse code directly ? Just to know : "Can I reverse it ?" yes / no . Like how can we say that hash algorithm cannot be reverse ? What can tell it ?